# Как правильно приостановить выполнение программы в objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Проблема в контроллере.

Мне нужно сделать так: меняем *UI*, спим 2 секунды, снова меняем *UI*. На деле происходит так, что мы спим 2 секунды, и только затем меняется *UI*.

То есть в коде:

```
[button1 setBackgtound ... ]
[NSTread sleepForTimeInterval: 2]
[button2 setBackground ...]
```

А при запуске сначала ждёт 2 секунды, и потом меняет у обеих.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше не делайте sleep главного потока, потому что это блокирует юзер-ивенты и изменения UI. 
Отложите обновление button2 на 2 секунды с помощью GCD:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [button2 setBackground ...]; 
});
```

Comment: Настя, большое спасибо! Все работает, как надо